# How to extract the numbers into a separate array from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given this string

```
"In 2015, I want to know how much does iPhone 6+ cost?"
```

how can I return `[2015, 6]`?

My first attempt at this was

```
numbers = str.tr("^0-9", '')
```

but that produces `20156`.

Comment: I see what you're saying @Ilya. But I think mine may be different because I'm explicitly asking for a return of an Array. Where as the other question is not.

Comment: "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" If all you tried was a single attempt using `tr`, then you need to do more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
numbers = str.scan(/\d+/)
# => ["2015", "6"]
```

Comment: Add `.map(&:to_i)` for integers, plus add `/\-?\d+/` for possible negative values.

Answer (score 1):

`scan` is better, but this also works.

```
"In 2015, I want to know how much does iPhone 6+ cost?".gsub(/\D/,' ').split
  #=> ["2015", "6"]
```